# Need help with 你们不是向着我的吗？

Tags: meaning

I found the phrase discussed in the title of this question on the 海贼王 manga (One Piece).  I have not found this phrase anywhere else, and have put this on other forums without much success.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it can be a real sentence in oral Chinese.

向 can become a verb. It has 2 possible meanings based on the situation.

First one mean "face to ..". The sentence can become "are you all facing to me?".

The other meaning "are you on my side"/"don't you support me".

For your case, I think it probably be the second meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that it's a translation typo. There is no verb in this sentence. It probably should be:

`你们不是想着我吗？` Meaning: `Don't you miss me?` or maybe: `Hyahyahya, didn't you all miss me after this long time??` Depends a bit on the context.

What's the context of the story? Is it when some bad guy gives a surprising visit or something like that? Then my answer is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is certain that this sentence means 'why don't your guys stand by me as you did before？'